# Why does the following flash not initially load in firefox, but works in chrome and IE

Tags: asp.net, flash

The following flash does not initially load in firefox, but if I click the second tab on the right, and then go back to the first, it loads.  This works in Chrome and IE.  Here is the [webpage](http://spectrumbridge.com/products-services/specex.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd, normally things dont work in IE but do in Chrome and Firefox. Upgrade your Flash Player is my advice

Answer (score 0):

Have you ruled out the possibility of it being a browser problem and not related to the site?

Does Firefox do this for any other sites?

Try clearing you cache and upgrading your Flash plugin to rule out the browser.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, a timing issue. Flash doesn't keep a network stack, it merely passes network calls to the browser, so any kind of logic that is sensitive to the timing or order of loads, load events, etc., can function differently from browser to browser.

But it's impossible to say more without seeing some code.